# Call Php controller function with AJAX Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I , im working with Ajax and Codeigniter to call function client-server

the php

```
public function mainViewClean() {


        unset($_SESSION[$this::jsondevices]);
        unset($_SESSION[$this::jsontags]);
       return "Ready";
    }
//route $route['cleantags']       = 'user/mainViewClean';
```

And ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn_recargar").button().click(function(){

            //window.location.href = "<?= base_url('home')?>";
             $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'<?php echo base_url("cleantags"); ?>',
                data:{'id':100},
                success:function(data){
                 //window.location.href = "<?= base_url('home')?>";
                    alert(data);
                }
            });

   });
});
</script>
```

The function excuse good , but javascript don't show any data , what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `return` into :

```
echo "Ready";
```

If you're sending an array, at server side you need to `json_encode`, example :

```
// encode array into json string format
echo json_encode( array( 'name' => 'Osman' ) );
```

And in Js, you have 2 options, the 1st solution is :

```
success : function ( data ) {
   // data now is coming in this form { "name" : "osman" }
   // as the string data is coming from server-side
   // you must parse it back into Javascript object
   var newData = JSON.parse( data );
}
```

And the 2nd option is, add `dataType` properties inside ajax properties like following :

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  dataType : 'json', // with this, no need to write JSON.parse()
  ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks , If I need send object , frist I need encode right?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the ajax call reads the response from the server, and that response must be rendered as some type of readable data, such as `application/json` or `text/html`.

In order to write that data, you need to `echo` it from the server with PHP.

The `return` statement doesn't write data, it simply returns at the server level.

If you want to communicate between `PHP` functions, you have to use `return`. But if you want to output some data, you have to use `echo`

**Client side**

```
$.ajax({
             url:'<?php echo base_url("cleantags"); ?>',
             dataType: 'application/json',
             success:function(response)
             {
                  alert(response.foo);
             }
      })
```

**Server Side**

```
public function mainViewClean() 
   {
        unset($_SESSION[$this::jsondevices]);
        unset($_SESSION[$this::jsontags]);
        echo json_encode( array("foo"=>"Ready"));
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new as I only have been using AJAX , but I think your code has a few syntactical errors.

- data: { id:100 }  with no quotations around id.

I advise you need to look at more examples of ajax calls to fix these little errors.

You said your JS is working but not showing data?

Comment: Quotations not required for `id`, just `data:{id:100}` is enough, and `.button()` function is part of `Jquery UI`.

Comment: True it is changes the element to a clickable button. searched and found it in the documentation